# in IntelliJ Java's Code Style how do we set it up to require blank line between annotated fields and no blank line between non-annotated fields

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When the fields have no annotation I want to keep them together

```
public class MyPojo {

  public String a;
  public String b;
}
```

but if a field is annotated I want a blank line above the annotation

```
public class MyPojo {

  @JsonProperty("a")
  public String a;

  @JsonProperty("b")
  public String b;
}
```

is there a configuration of settings in IntelliJ that would give me this behavior? my current relevant settings are below:

- Preferences

  - Editor

    - Code Style

      - Java

        - Wrapping and Braces

          - **Field annotations: Wrap always**

            - **Do not wrap after single annotation: unchecked**
        - Blank Lines

          - Keep Maximum Blank Lines

            - **In declarations: 1**
          - Minimum Blank Lines

            - **Around field in interface: 0**
            - **Around field: 0**

Comment: This would be very useful to know! I can't find the solution either.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look for all possible options in formatting settings but could not find anything that can let us have a blank line before annotations. I could just found that we can add a space after annotations but nothing is there for the line.

I am also interested if you could find it. :)